powershell build step in Teamcity does not behave the same way as "Open Terminal" for Agent
I have TeamCity Deployment, where i want to use different Node version for different Projects. I have added frontend-maven-plugin which installs differnt node version, also have manually installed the version in Agent machine. Now i am trying to add a Build-Step as command line before running maven, to change the node version. I am trying to use "nvm use 18" which should change the node version.
This works fine, when i try it from the terminal which opens when i click on "Open Terminal" at the Agent window. But when i perform same thing by adding a Build step (Either command line or powershell) it runs forever and not actually changing the version.
Could please someone guide me as to what could be the issue?
enter image description here
enter image description here
I am expecting that node version should be changed even when using teamcity build step
 <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.12.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install node and npm</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <!-- optional: default phase is
                                "generate-resources" -->
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>maven run install</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>maven run angular build-web-prod</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>run build-file-prod</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v18.17.0</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>9.6.7</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin> 

, 


Why do you need to change the version if it isn't used by the build? AFAIR, maven-frontend-plugin uses the version it downloads, not the one set in the environment.

Hi Alex, my maven-frontend-plugin has 18, but i can see in teamcity, if the environment version is 12, it still complains, may be I am doing something wrong in maven-frontend-plugin
